# Reading C# dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary variable in C# (ASP.NET). I want to send this data to Javascript. I am using this code to serialize it and send to javascript.

```
Dictionary<string, string> chat;
chat = new Dictionary<string, string>();

chat.Add("Sam", "How are you?");
chat.Add("Rita", "I am good");
var serialize = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

Response.Write(serialize.Serialize(chat));
```

On the Javascript page, I am calling this page using this;

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "TextChatCalls/getChat.aspx",
 type: "POST",
 context: document.body,
 success: function (response) {
          var Chats = response.split('\n')[0];
          alert(Chats);

          }
 });
```

The value in Chats var is `{"Sam":"How are you?","Rita":"I am good"}`

I don't know how do I read this value in Chats. Can I anyhow convert this into a 2D array and read it as array[0][0], array[1][0] etc. ?

Thanks.

EDIT:
One more confusion is that, the response object, returned from ASP.NET, contains

```
{"Sam":"How are you?","Rita":"I am good"}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="getChat.aspx?Id=141755" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZJctiKZK4rXVndR3mbGssIarCrOF" />
</div>

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And not just `{"Sam":"How are you?","Rita":"I am good"}` as expected. And hence I have to split the response object by `var Chats = response.split('\n')[0];` which makes it an string!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You read like this:

```
alert(Chats["Sam"]);
```

(so like a C# Dictionary :-). You read/write to it using something like `Chats["propertyName"]`)

or, to go through each value:

```
for (var c in Chats)
{
    if (Chats.hasOwnProperty(c)) 
    {
        alert(c + '   ' + Chats[c]);
    }
}
```

Note that this is different than C#. In C# `c` would contain a `KeyValuePair<>` containing both the key and the value. In Javascript `c` is only the key and to get the value you have to use `Chats[c]`.

(the reasoning for `hasOwnProperty` is here http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/)

Now... If you really want to split it:

```
var array = [];

for (var c in Chats)
{
    if (Chats.hasOwnProperty(c)) 
    {
        array.push([c, Chats[c]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why, but my response object contains this value "{"Sam":"How are you?","Rita":"I am good"}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="getChat.aspx?Id=141755" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZJctiKZK4rXVndR3mbGssIarCrOF" />
</div>

    <div>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
"

Comment: @Joy You have to do a `Response.End()` after the `Response.Write()`, otherwhise you'll send the whole aspx page after the JSON :-)

Comment: Better still you should be using an ashx handler or a page method. There's no point going through the aspx lifecycle if you're not going to output the page content.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the data type json to your ajax request

```
$.ajax({
 url: "TextChatCalls/getChat.aspx",
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "json"
 context: document.body,
 success: function (response) {
          // do something with response
 });
```

This will make `response`  a javascript object that you can access like this

```
alert(response["sam"]) //How are you?
```

to split that up into a 2d array just do this

```
var Chats = [];
for ( k in response ){
  Chats[Chats.length] = [k, response[k]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the important point here is that you properly understand what is going on on the JavaScript client side. The datatype that arrives on the JavaScript client side is a JSON string. JSON (= JavaScript Object Notation) can directly be interpreted by JavaScript.

A JavaScript object looks as follows:

```
var anObject = { name: "Sam", surname: "abc"};
```

You can access the properties of a JavaScript object either through a somewhat Dictionary-similar way like

```
anObject["name"] //will get "Sam"
```

or directly (property notation)

```
anObject.name
```

Instead a similar JSON string would look like

```
var aJsonString = '{ "name": "Sam", "surname": "abc"}'
```

Now to convert the JSON string to a JavaScript object you need to parse it. jQuery does this already for you, otherwise you can invoke `JSON.parse(aJsonString)` and you'll get a valid JavaScript object.

Here I did a quick example: http://jsbin.com/adejev/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core, I used this inside the `cshtml` file. Basically I rebuilt the entire Dictionary into Javascript. The reason for this approach is because I have subfunctions in Javascript that won't be able to call the server model functions with dynamic parameters on events like keypress.

```
var ModelZxcvWarnLookup = {};
@foreach (var kvp in Model.View.ZxcvbnWarningMsgLocalization)
{
    @:ModelZxcvWarnLookup['@Html.Raw(@kvp.Key)'] = '@Html.Raw(@kvp.Value)';
}
```

Inspecting the html page fetched by the browser:

```
var ModelZxcvWarnLookup = {};
ModelZxcvWarnLookup["Straight rows of keys are easy to guess"] = "Chinese Straight rows of keys are easy to guess";
ModelZxcvWarnLookup["Short keyboard patterns are easy to guess"] = "Chinese Short keyboard patterns are easy to guess";
ModelZxcvWarnLookup['Repeats like "aaa" are easy to guess'] = 'Repeats like "aaa" are easy to guess';
```