# SignalR and MVC bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle, signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR with MVC bundle, but having problem finding out how to include the /signalr/hubs script into the bundle. For now I have to insert the path in between jquery.signalR and my code. That will result in three javascript file requests.

Is there any way to include /signalr/hubs into my mvc bundle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default /signalr/hubs script is generated dynamically by the runtime on the first request and then cached.

You can use hubify.exe (see http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/06/10/signalr-0-5-1-released.aspx for details) to pre-generate the file yourself, so you can add it into the MVC bundle.

Comment: This works well in most cases. Except if the site is hosted in a virtual directory. The hubs js generates this `$.hubConnection("/signalr" ...` which will not work if the site is in a virtual directory.

Comment: Went to the link above 
and the link to generate hubify.exe is in 
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/SignalR.ProxyGenerator
and that does not work

Comment: It's not super well documented but you can do this now using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils. Quick steps:

* Install Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils using nuget
* Add something like this to your Post build event:
"$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils.2.2.2\tools\signalr" ghp "$(TargetPath)"
XCOPY "$(TargetDir)server.js" "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\hubs" /R /Y

Answer (score 49):

A bit late, but here is my contribution:
Create a javascript file with the following contents:

```
(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/signalr/hubs",
        dataType: "script",
        async: false
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Then add the file to the bundles collection.
This will load the "/signalr/hubs" code for you.

Comment: cache: true if you want to benefit from client cache

Comment: This seems to work with IIS Express but will fail with a 404 error when you deploy to full IIS. [How to reference the dynamically generated proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#dynamicproxy)

Comment: @KTW Why "async: false" ?

Comment: @sports because you don't want other things that depend on it firing before it is loaded.

Comment: @DarylTeo and in terms of efficiency, this is equal to putting a script html tag in the head?

Comment: @sports I'm afraid I'm not qualified to answer that. It won't load in the head though, I think.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the code. But isn't signalr/hubs just downloaded separately and not in the bundle? So the only benefit is that you save a line of <script> code in the .cshtml file ?

Comment: I have no words to thank you enough

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I would like to add the following for SignalR 2.x. I really wanted to bundle the proxy using SquishIt and by trial and error I managed to come up with the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs

var resolver = new DefaultHubManager(new DefaultDependencyResolver());
var proxy = new DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator(resolver, new NullJavaScriptMinifier());
string iCanHazScriptNao = proxy.GenerateProxy("/signalr");
```

Answer (score 1):

From [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#dynamicproxy), using the SignalR.Utils NuGet package, I found that I needed to be in the directory with the DLL that has the hub in it:

(*assuming you have a standard solution structure and are using 2.2.0 of SignalR.Utils*)

```
cd C:\YourSolution\YourProjectWithTheHub\bin\Debug
..\..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils.2.2.0\tools\signalr.exe ghp
```

After running the tool, there will be a `server.js` file in the directory you ran it from (in this case, `Debug`).

(*Note: I couldn't get it to work when specifying the path with the /p flag, and for some reason even when it does work, it creates a temp directory with the signalr.exe file in it*)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the code with the [`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils/) NuGet package. Add that to your project, then you can add the below as a post-build script (Project -> {project name} Properties -> Build Events). It should be a post-build script and not pre- since you want it to build against your updated hub code after it's compiled.

It will find whatever version of the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils` package that you have installed and put the server.js file in the Scripts folder.

You must also have a version redirect for `Newtonsoft.Json` in your web.config file (assuming your project uses `Newtonsoft.Json`). This is because signalr.exe is built against version 6.0.0 and you're likely using a newer version. The `/configFile` switch is to tell it to use your project's config file so that it uses the redirect.

Post-build script:

```
cd $(ProjectDir)\Scripts
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%p IN (`dir ..\..\packages /b /ad ^| find "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils"`) DO (
  set "UTILSPATH=%%p"
)
$(SolutionDir)\packages\%UTILSPATH%\tools\net40\signalr.exe ghp /path:$(TargetDir) /configFile:$(TargetPath).config
```

Then include `~/Scripts/server.js` in your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I used @KTW response mentioned on this Thread and here is the complete change

**BundleConfig**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.multiselect.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.jstepper.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/underscore.min.js"
        ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/SignalRScripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/signalRBundle.js",
            "~/Scripts/Views/Search/SignalRFunctions.js"));
    }
}
```

**SignalRFunctions.js**

```
    $(function() {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var usersHub = $.connection.currentUsersHub;
    //Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    usersHub.client.broadcastMessage = function(reservationNumber, usrName) {
        //Message broadcast from server
        //now find the id with reservationNumber on the page and to that append the user name
        var id = '#' + reservationNumber;
        if ($(id).length) {
            if (usrName.length) {
                itemsOpened($(id), usrName);
            } else {
                itemsClosed($(id));
            }
        } 
        //else {
        //    //is it possible that server broad casted for a reservationNumber and is not available at the client?
        //}
    };

    //Accepts dictionary from hub and goes through search results
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776337/reading-c-sharp-dictionary-in-javascript
    usersHub.client.broadcastCollection = function (reservationNumberAndUsers) {
       for (var resNumKey in reservationNumberAndUsers) {
            if (reservationNumberAndUsers.hasOwnProperty(resNumKey)) {
                //Message broadcast from server
                //now find the id with ReservationNumber on the page and to that append the user name
                var id = '#' + resNumKey;
                if ($(id).length) {
                    if (reservationNumberAndUsers[resNumKey].length) {
                        itemsOpened($(id), reservationNumberAndUsers[resNumKey]);
                    } else {
                        itemsClosed($(id));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
                var searchedReservationNumbers = [];
                if (typeof jsData !== 'undefined') {
                    if (jsData && jsData.length) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < jsData.length; i++) {
                            searchedReservationNumbers.push(jsData[i].UReservationNumber);
                        }
                        if (searcheduReservationNumbers.length !== 0) {
                            usersHub.server.getWorkingUsersOnUReservationNumber(searcheduReservationNumbers);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).fail(function () { console.log('Could not Connect To SignalrHub!'); });
        /*In case we would decide to continuously reconnect making connection to server.
        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                    $.connection.hub.start();
                },
                5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
        });*/

function itemsOpened(elem, id) {
    var item = "Opened By - " + id;
    elem.prop('title', item);
    elem.css('background-color', 'chocolate');
};

function itemsClosed(elem) {
    elem.prop('title', "");
    elem.css('background-color', '');
};
});
```

**signalRBundle.js**

```
(function ($) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/signalr/hubs",
    dataType: "script",
    async: false
});
}(jQuery));
/* Source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556110/signalr-and-mvc-bundle */
```

**SomePartialView.cshtml**
Instead of writing below in above partial view

```
@using Localization
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model NameSpace.ViewModels.FilterVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Strings.Filter;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        ---SOME CODE HERE 
    </div>

}

@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var jsData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Views/Search/SignalRFunctions.js"></script>
}
```

This changed to

```
 @using Localization
    @using Newtonsoft.Json
    @model NameSpace.ViewModels.FilterVM

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = Strings.Filter;
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            ---SOME CODE HERE 
        </div>

    }

    @section scripts
    {
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var jsData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/SignalRScripts")
    }
```

Notice

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/SignalRScripts")
```

in partial view above.Without @KTW file above(ajax request to /signalr/hubs)

```
var usersHub = $.connection.currentUsersHub;
```

was always coming as null.

Comment: As @mathew leger pointed out below

This seems to work with IIS Express but will fail with a 404 error when you deploy to full IIS.