# SignalR $.connection not defined, intermittent successful definition on some PCs

Tags: signalr

I have a MVC5 project using signalr to perform updates to a list. Inside script.js, there is a variable link to defined as `var link = $.connection.hub`. There is also a bundleconfig file to load the dependent scripts, signalr/jquery and jquery in the proper order of course.
The script `/signalr/hubs` is loaded in from the html manually.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/signalr").Include(
"~/Scripts/script.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"));
```

When the VS 2013 Web project is run, it works fine until the project is copied over to another PC that it does not work as intended. The variable `link` is undefined as `$.connection` is undefined too (`$` is defined though).

I presume that `jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js` is not read or executed at all.

Questions:

- Might this have anything to do with the environment of the PCs? (Windows 7 is OK, Windows 8 is not OK)
- What could prevent `jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js` from running?
- Does creating a new View/Controller play a part in the error (creating a view, using a layout page)?

Answer (score 0):

Please see similar question: [SignalR and MVC bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556110/signalr-and-mvc-bundle) as it shows how to add SignalR into an MVC bundle. I think their answer should help solve your problem.

I would comment instead of answer, but I don't have enough reputation.