# webforms asp.net and signalr, works only in one page

Tags: signalr

I develop a webforms asp.net site with signalr to real time communications.

I have master.page with everything related to signalr defined.

```
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/signalr/hubs") %>
```

In one content page i added another js file to handle signalr stuff, like this:

```
 $(function () {
            $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function () {
                    console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.hub.id);

                });
});
```

Everything fine!

Then i tried to spread the access to signalR hub to others pages including the master page.

So, i put this in master direct on page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function () {
                    console.log('Now connected MASTER, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);

                });
});
</script>
```

All fine, but the client connects two time, but with same connectionID. Is there anyhow i can connect just one time and share HubProxy between master and content pages??

But, when i try to render another content page based on that master, i've got a error "hub is undefined".

The only page works ok with that master page is the first one with js separated to signalr.

here is the hub code as required:

```
 public class GameHub : Hub
    {
        private const long tempoJogada = 30000;
        private const long tempoTruco = 30000;
        private const long tempoMao11 = 30000;

        private readonly static Model.Truco _truco = new Model.Truco();
        private Mesa _mesa;

        private static int JogadoresOnline = 0;

        public GameHub()
        {
            _mesa = _truco.Saloes[0].Mesas[0];

            Debug.WriteLine("criou hub : " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        public List<Jogador> RetornaJogadoresMesa()
        {
            return _mesa.Jogadores;
        }


        public async Task<int> EntrarMesa(Jogador jogador)
        {
            int posicaoMesa = 0;
            Jogador jogadorServer = _mesa.Jogadores.SingleOrDefault(jo => jo.Nome == jogador.Nome);

            jogador.ClientGuid = new Guid(Context.ConnectionId);
            if (_mesa.Jogadores.Count(jo => jo.Nome == jogador.Nome) == 0)
            {

                posicaoMesa = _mesa.EntrarMesa(jogador);
                if (posicaoMesa > 0)
                {
                    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, _mesa.NomeMesa);
                    Clients.Group(_mesa.NomeMesa).entrarMesa(jogador.Nome, posicaoMesa);
                }


                if (_mesa.QuantidadeVagas == 0)
                {
                    IniciarJogo();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // ja estava na mesa (reconectando)
                await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, _mesa.NomeMesa);
                if (jogadorServer != null)
                    posicaoMesa = _mesa.Jogadores.IndexOf(jogadorServer) + 1;
            }

            return posicaoMesa;
        }

        private void IniciarJogo()
        {
            EnviaCartas(true);

            _mesa.EstaJogando = true;
        }
.
.
.
.
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to have only one connection? having the code in the master page only provides the convenience of the sharing the code in all pages, the SignalR javascript api is available so that real time communication between pages is possible, if that is not what you need, maybe you should make the connection using a service layer

Comment: ok, but my problem is, when a inserted the script to the master every content page derived from this is getting "hub is undefined". As i mentioned only the first content page i started is working. Thanks

Comment: well, for that please post the code of the hub as well, to reproduce the issue

Comment: The partial hub code is above. Thanks again, its driving me crazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure this is the cause, but i think maybe its related to how you are referencing the scripts, for me this is how it worked:

**1. Define hubs.js**

Using the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13259957/895167) 
define a js file named hubs.js containing

```
(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/signalr/hubs",
        dataType: "script",
        async: false
    });
}(jQuery));
```

**2. Define a Bundle**

In **BundleConfig.cs**

If you have `<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />` in your master page then add

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/SignalR").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/hubs.js"));
```

Else add

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/SignalR").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/hubs.js"));
```

**3. Add the Script Reference**

And after the bundle add

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(
                "signalr",
                new ScriptResourceDefinition
                {
                    Path = "~/bundles/SignalR",
                });
```

**4. Use the Script Reference**

In the master page add the following under **ScriptManager/Scripts** for more info on this check [ASP.NET 4.5 ScriptManager Improvements in WebForms](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884)

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="signalr" />
        .
        .
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

**Edit**

If the application is not hosted on the root, the hub.js code need to be changed to the following:

```
(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "signalr/hubs",
        dataType: "script",
        async: false
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The leading "/" causes the **url** to point to the root always

```
http://domain/signalr/hubs
```

but without it, it will point to the hosting folder

```
http://domain/yourAppFolder/signalr/hubs
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I just keep the scripts out of blundling and minification, to keep the scenario simpler, but actualy it realy seems to be something related to scripts. So i follow your instructions and put back blundle, and the result changed, now the script in the master connects to the hub, but it says "HubProxy is now undefined", by the way, the page i develop first still working with no problems at all(weird). I will go deep tomorrow, and try to figure out. Thanks again

Comment: @gilberto you are welcome, maybe the way you defined the scripts was working in the page but not in the master because of your app structure, like the page in the root, but the master in a folder....etc as for the hub proxy, check the edit

Comment: it works thank you very much, couldnt vote up due to reputation

Comment: @gilberto Iam having the same issue can you tell me where to add ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(
                "signalr",
                new ScriptResourceDefinition
                {
                    Path = "~/bundles/SignalR",
                });