# JQuery get select list option

Tags: c#, jquery, dictionary

Scenario:

I have a dictionary of integers and booleans.

I am trying to loop around a dictionary. If the value of the dictionary is true, I would then like to get the specific select list option based off of the dictionary key.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            @foreach (var item in Model.RPDisplay)
    {
        if (item.Value == true) {
            // Get the option from the select list where the value of the option is equal to item.Key

        }
    }
        });
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is another way to do that and I suggest that

```
var map = $.map(Model.RPDisplay, function(n) {
    if(n.value)
        return n;
});
```

Now you have a array of true value items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this brought the error message of : Unterminated template literal. I don't think you can use a dictionary in JQuery, I moved the dictionary and set it as a variable but it still said the same thing

Comment: I don't know what is Model.RPDisplay but it works for iterable objects. Maybe you should give more detail. Or search for how to convert Model.RPDisplay to iterable object.

Comment: It's a dictionary, I thought it was iterable

Comment: Maybe you should share Model.RPDisplay console output with us if it is possible

Comment: This is the beginning line and also where the error is thrown: var map = $.map(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Boolean], function (n) {

Comment: Ok sorry about the mess. There is some c# code I didn't see in the block.

Comment: Yeah, im sorry about this too. It's driving me crazy

Comment: You should first add your dictionary to javascript array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776337/reading-c-sharp-dictionary-in-javascript and then iterate in the javascript.